# pass template as input of another component and bindings in the final component

Tags: angular

I would like to pass a template written in the HTML of a component as an input of another component.
I can achieve this step with

```
<ng-template #tpl><my-component></my-component></ng-template>
```

and getting it in the final component

```
@Input() tpl: TemplateRef<any>;
```

and use it in the HTML of the final component

```
 <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="tpl"></ng-container>
```

This works fine BUT I would like to add bindings to my-component beacause it takes inputs and generates outputs. I would like to add these bindings in the final component.

The goal is for the final component to display any dynamic components (inherited from a mother class) and manages in this final component the inputs and ouputs of these components (which will have the same interface)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing the template through an input, you should use ViewChild. This will allow you to have a reference to that component and perform the same public actions as if you had extended the class. For example, let's say the child template's class has a move function. Anyone can access it by the following:

**html**

`<example>sample content</example>`

**typescript**

```
@ViewChild('example') example: ExampleComponent;

...
ngAfterViewInit() {
     this.example.move();
}
```

Note: You can pass in a component, directive or ElementRef!

Comment: what about inputs that I vould like to pass ?
I could do this.example.input1 = 'my value'; ?
Same for outputs ?
Problem is that for using viewchil I need to know the component I want to use, which is nt genreic and does not fill my needs.